# Запуск js из другого js

Tags: javascript, spa

При клике на ссылку у меня срабатывает скрипт, который меняет содержимое страницы.
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы каждый раз, при нажатии на одну из ссылок, запускался скрипт. Причём каждый раз заново.
Пробую с помощью `$.getScript("swipe.js");`
Почему-то не срабатывает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно решить мою проблему.

```
 const ids = ['index', 'profile', 'swipe', 'swipe_ex'];

function showPage(pageId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (pageId == ids[i]) {
            document.getElementById(pageId).style.display = "block";
            if (pageId != 'index')
                $('#' + pageId).load(pageId + '.html');
            if (pageId == 'swipe')
                $.getScript("swipe.js");
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#' + pageId).load(pageId + '.html', function() {
  if (pageId == 'swipe')
    $.getScript("swipe.js");
});
```

Comment: оказалось, что надо установить путь от корня, то есть js/swipe.js